# Excel VBA: Hyperlink that creates a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Wondering if this is even possible, but:

So I got a macro button that inserts values into the sheet from a UserForm, and here's a visual example how it approximately looks like:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>OrderID:</td>
    <td>Product</td> 
    <td>Q</td>
    <td>Invoice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Potato</td> 
    <td>1337</td>
    <td><a href="url">Open Invoice</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The "Open Invoice" link I create with this code:

```
    Sheets("Sales").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Sales").Cells(emptyRow, 9), "", Sheets("Sales").Name, "", "Open Invoice"
```

I would like that, whenever I click "Open Invoice", it would create a new Sheet (preferably a new Excel window) and then the data transfers into a template (the transferring and template I think I will manage myself)

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`?

Comment: @findwindow alright, alright. Step forward. Now the issue is that when I click "Open Invoice" link it firstly drops an error about Invalid Reference since there is no link under "Open Invoice". How do I go about that? Possible to insert an empty link so nothing happens?

Comment: How do you click a link when there's no link?

Comment: `Sheets("Sales").Name` is not a valid address.

Comment: @DavidZemens yeah, I need it empty, basically I just want a text formatted as hyperlink so I can click on it but the hyperlink itself should lead nowhere, but the click opens a new sheet.

Comment: WHy not just make it a normal text cell, and *format it* to *look like* a hyperlink. Then use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to perform the rest of the work?

Comment: @DavidZemens I think it would be easier to just link back to the main worksheet, that way nothing would happen. Tho I don't know where exactly to put the link that leads to the same sheet "Sales" and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this to set your hyperlink:

```
Dim hlRange as Range
Set hlRange = Sheets("Sales").Cells(emptyRow, 9)
With hlRange.Hyperlinks
    .Delete
    .Add Anchor:=hlRange, _
         Address:="", _
         SubAddress:=hlRange.Address, _
         TextToDisplay:="Open Invoice"
End With
```

This creates a hyperlink that links back to itself, so it's a *valid* reference but it doesn't *go anywhere else*.

Then, using the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event procedure to create a new Workbook from your template, and from there you can insert the data as needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
' If there are other hyperlinks in this sheet which should NOT trigger the new file, then you will need to add an Intersect test and exit sub early.

'Add a new workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("path to template file")  '## Modify as needed
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)                         '## Modify as needed

'Add the data to the new sheet in new workbook
'  -- code here, or call another procedure to do the operation --

End Sub
```

Comment: What's Range (D5) for?

Comment: @user3688039 in which context? It's used in the `FollowHyperlink` procedure as logical control-flow statement so that other hyperlink(s) (if there are other hyperlinks in other cells) do not trigger the "Add new workbook".  In the other snippet of code assigning the hyperlink, IDK what it's for, it's part of your OP code, so I assumed that was necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't mentioned Range (D5) anywhere.

Comment: @user3688039 ahhh my bad. That was the range I was using to test the code, since you didn't provide a full example I had to hardcode some elements. In any case, above code "D5" is simply the cell wherein the hyperlink should exist. So, modify accordingly :)

Comment: I modified the code to *set* the hyperlink, but you'll need to modify the `FollowHyperlink` event procedure, probably.

Comment: Alright, everything seems mostly legit. Now that I have 2 open workbooks, how do I get data from the main one to the template? This would be the last step for everything to be perfect. :p

Comment: In your OP, you said: *the transferring and template I think I will manage myself*. [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=excel%20copy%20values%20to%20another%20workbook) and please demonstrate some effort, and if you get stuck with specific problem, update your Q with the code that you're trying to use, and description of how it's failing you, and I can help with that.